# How to stop something from appearing again once it has value in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know it may have been asked before, but I need help.
I have a table customer with customerID as PK, a table car with carID as PK, and table reservation with reservationID as PK and carID,customerID as FKs.
In a datagridview I executed a query to see the cars and rent one, how is it possible that when a customer rents a car, not to show him other cars?
In other words I want customers with rents not to see available cars.

Comment: What language do you want to use? Purely SQL or is your application written in Java or other sort of language?

Comment: you can in where check on customerId(if in booking exist record with this customerId then don't show any info)

Comment: Is it not ok for someone to rent two cars at once, if they want to? But anyway what is the context? In a search screen you mean? So I guess your reservations table will need some start and end dates for the rental, and then it the user searches for cars using dates where they already have a rental on (at least one of) those days, you don't show them any results. So basically, if that is the situation, then you want a query which matches overlapping dates...you can find examples of that kind of thing online

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, if I understood your question correctly:

```
-- Current customer, should come from outside (provided by the application, etc.)
declare @CustomerId int = ...;

select c.*
from dbo.Cars c
where
  -- Exclude cars booked by other customers
  not exists (
    select 0 from dbo.Reservations r
    where r.CarId = c.Id
      and r.CustomerId != @CustomerId
  )
  -- Exclude everything else if the customer already has a booking
  and not exists (
    select 0 from dbo.Reservations r
    where r.CustomerId = @CustomerId
      and r.CarId != c.CarId
    );
```